# How to know what certificate is associated with a connected app?

Tags: connected-apps, jwt

I have a connected app and I would like to know what certificate it is associated with. How does one find out that information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see the certificate's subject in the admin UI on the connected app details page (Setup > Build > Apps > Create ... find your app and click on the app name). The `Digital Certificate` field will show you the certificate's subject, it might look something like this:

```
C=USA, ST=CA, L=San Francisco, O=Salesforce.com, OU=00D..., CN=ACME Inc. 2020 12:00:00 GMT
```

To download the certificate in its entirety, you can pull the connected app definition via Metadata API using your favorite SF metadata-capable client (e.g. Workbench) with the following package.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>NameOfMyApp</members>
        <name>ConnectedApp</name>
    </types>
    <version>47.0</version>
</Package>
```

Here's a redacted response, only the cert is shown for relevancy:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ConnectedApp xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <oauthConfig>
        <certificate>MIID2DCCAsACC...vO8w==</certificate>
    </oauthConfig>
</ConnectedApp>
```

The value of `certificate` element is PEM-encoded X.509 cert.

Comment: I am trying to identify the connected apps in my org that uses a certificate, but unable to find the 'Digital Certificate' field, any idea?

Comment: The Digital Certificate field is only visible when you View or Edit rather than Manage a Connected App. If your only option in the App Manager is Manage, then it's not a Connected App you created.