# Who gets notified when a certificate expires in Connected Apps?

Tags: email, api, connected-apps

We are using a JWT flow for our Connected App to enable API connectivity between Salesforce and our external servers. When we upload a digital certificate to the Connected App page, it shows the expiry date of the certificate on the Connected App page, but it is not visible on the "Certificates and Key Management" settings page.

How will we know if a certificate from one of our many Connected Apps is due to expire? Will we receive an alert similar to the alerts for Certificates found on the "Certificates and Key Management" page? If yes, who does this get sent to? The Salesforce administrator or the Contact Email address found on the Connected App details?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do expired certificates for salesforce connected applications block connections?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/313488/do-expired-certificates-for-salesforce-connected-applications-block-connections)

Comment: You don't get notified unless it's in Cert and Key Mgmt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All System Administrators will be part of the receipient group for this email as per this  Salesforce [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385781&type=1).

*Certificate expiration notifications are sent out to certain Users in an organization for certificates that are about to expire to prevent any service disruptions, such as not being able to access a custom domain. These are currently sent at the 60-day mark, 30-day mark, 10-day mark and day of expiry to Users with **Modify All Data** and **View Setup and configuration** profile permission, along with all the system administrators.*